# How to remove weird screen glitches in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: 13.04, screen

A couple of weeks ago I started noticing these weird black lines appearing on my screen every now and then (can't really say when). It never happened before. Last time it happened i took the screenshot below. 
I have a Lenovo Z580 Laptop with Intel graphics and Nvidia GT graphics. I use bumblebee and tlp for power management. I don't know if those apps have anything to do with it.

The glitches go away when i change the active window or move a window around on the screen. I have got the feeling that it might have something to do with chrome browser being open....

Does anyone have an idea how to get rid of this? It's not really a critical problem but it is really annoying. 
I appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot! :)

[image: Glitches appear every now and then and go away when I move a window around or open different window.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reinstalling your Nvidia Drivers using the following commands in the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

If this doesn't help, bumblebee could be the issue and you could try to remove it:

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee*
```

Comment: Here's what happened. The problem didn't happen again for a week or so. So it may have gone away by itself just through some update in the meantime. Just to be safe I have then also reinstalled the nvidia drivers and the glitches have not appeared again.